# Having Problems running Python on old CE device

Tags: python, c, windows-ce

I have a Python interpreter that runs on a CE device and is a C application. Currently the device comes configure with a root '\' folder and a '\Application' folder. If I install and run python on the '\' drive everything is fine, but if I try to put it on the '\Application' drive it will not run.

In digging further, the problem is with the CreateFileW call. When trying to access '\PythonLib' I get a normal error code of 80 saying the file exists, when I try to access '\Application\PythonLib' I get an error code of 5, or Access is Denied.

Has anyone had any experience with this?  Any C++ app we develop in Visual Studio 2008 and run on the device has no problem accessing '\Application', but anything we try with Python can not seem to resolve that path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the problem was the attributes on the CreateFile calls. For some reason on our device the '\' directory needs different attributes then the '\Application\' folder.  mainly I needed to add the FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS bit to the FlagAndAttributes field.